# Enhancing a non-multithreaded Circular buffer

Tags: c++, queue, circular-list

Looking to get some feedback on a simple non-multithreaded circular buffer.

Ideally, I'd want to have a logic to prevent the data from getting overwritten but couldn't find a reasonable way.
For instance, if the buffer size is 3 and `Write` is invoked, it shouldn't proceed until the buffer is no longer full.

```
class Fifo
{
    public:
    void Write(uint8_t data)
    {   
        mBuffer[mWriteIdx++] = data;
        mWriteIdx %= BUFFER_SIZE;
        mIsFull = mWriteIdx == mReadIdx;
    }
    
    uint8_t Read() 
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            return 0; // considering 0 is an invalid data
        }
        
        uint8_t value = mBuffer[mReadIdx];
        
        mBuffer[mReadIdx++] = 0;   // null out the index
        mReadIdx %= BUFFER_SIZE;
        mIsFull = false;
        
        return value;
    }
    
    
    private:
    
    bool IsEmpty() const
    {
        return !mIsFull && mReadIdx == mWriteIdx;
    }
    
    // Member variables
    int mReadIdx = 0;
    int mWriteIdx = 0;
    
    static constexpr int BUFFER_SIZE = 4;
    uint8_t mBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    bool mIsFull = false;
};
```

[Here's](https://cplayground.com/?p=leopard-magpie-rabbit) a sample program with outputs

Answer (score 2):

**Advice I: `IsEmpty`**

```
bool IsEmpty() const
    {
        return !mIsFull && mReadIdx == mWriteIdx;
    }
```

Why not deploy a field

```
size_t size = 0;
```

counting the number of elements in the buffer? That way, your `IsEmpty` becomes much simpler:

```
bool IsEmpty() const 
{
    return size == 0;
}
```

**Advice II: Add `IsFull`**
How about this?

```
bool IsFull() const {
    return size == BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

**Advice III: Throwing appropriate exceptions**

I would throw an [`std::underflow_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/underflow_error) when trying to read from an empty buffer, and I would throw an [`std::overflow_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/overflow_error) when trying to write to a full buffer.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I thought about this implementation:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class Fifo
{
public:
    void Write(uint8_t data)
    {
        if (IsFull())
        {
            throw std::overflow_error("The buffer is full.");
        }

        mBuffer[(headIndex + size++) % BUFFER_SIZE] = data;
    }

    uint8_t Read()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            throw std::underflow_error("The buffer is empty.");
        }

        uint8_t value = mBuffer[headIndex++];
        headIndex %= BUFFER_SIZE;
        size--;
        return value;
    }


private:

    bool IsEmpty() const
    {
        return size == 0;
    }

    bool IsFull() const {
        return size == BUFFER_SIZE;
    }

    // Member variables
    size_t headIndex = 0;

    static constexpr int BUFFER_SIZE = 4;
    uint8_t mBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
    size_t size = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Fifo fifo;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        fifo.Write(i + 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::cout << unsigned(fifo.Read()) << "\n";
    }

    fifo.Write(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you misspelt `std::uint8_t` throughout.

Comment: `std::underflow_error` and `std::overflow_error` are not appropriate exceptions. They're used to indicate floating point underflow or numeric overflow. The right exception would be `std::logic_error`. However, exceptions are also not appropriate in general because they're only meant to be used in exceptional situations, and attempting to push to a ring buffer and checking whether this succeeded is a common operation. Simply returning `bool` would make more sense.

Comment: @JanSchultke Agreed. I will update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of throwing an exception if the buffer is full, is there a better way to approach it such that the requested data is 'not lost' and is rather queued as soon as there's space, it gets pushed into FIFO?

Comment: @xyf Basically, that's the same as having a larger buffer.

Comment: Does it ever make sense to overwrite the existing data than waiting for the buffer to have some space for new data to be written?

Answer (score 1):

Use of the type `uint8_t` suggests that you're either including the C-compatibility header `<stdint.h>` or have a `using` at global scope.

Don't do either of those things.  Include the C++ header `<cstdint>` and use the type it declares: `std::uint8_t`.

You might want to have

```
using value_type = std::uint8_t;
```

within the class.  That will be helpful if you make it a template in future.

---

I would have liked to see a full set of unit tests for this class - it's perfectly suited to such testing.